# while inserting it show type converting error

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

i am calling the validator method in Insert to check for empty text box...and print msg

it prints the msg but Show this msg i.e

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type float for property advance; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
```

the text box field which i am validating is float type...

can any body tell me how to remove this error.

this is the form tag

```
[form:input path="advance" id="addpa"]
```

..>> enttiy 
class name is order
private float advance ;
getter and setter method

Comment: The message **nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String** says that your property advance is empty, can you show your form?

Comment: yes its empty in the form how to handle ....

Comment: I mean show your html markup and your form objecct..

Comment: i have given it check it

Comment: you have path="adds" but your error message says property advance so try changing adds to advance,

Comment: bro my property name is advance only but still its showing that error....the error msg displays in the jsp it self....

Comment: well.. in the markup you provided it isn't, it says form:input path="adds"

Comment: sorrry for that but actually its advance...it was a mistake...sorry to provide a wrong info....my entity name is float advance,and path name is advance.

Comment: Well now I am confused.. could you post your whole form, your form object (entity) and your controller?